Multithreaded Alpha-beta pruning for playing Connect Four in Java
Intro
(The entire repository is in GitHub.)
This time, I have parallelized the famous Alpha-beta pruning algorithm. The idea is that the parallel algorithm descends in a game tree (at least) 2 levels down (reaching the seed level), and for each state at the seed level runs in parallel it in a single-threaded Alpha-beta pruning to compute their scores. The rest is a sequential search starting from the root all the way down to the seed layer. Basically, this is the divide-and-conquer approach.
Code
com.github.coderodde.game.zerosum.impl.ParallelConnectFourAlphaBetaPruningSearchEngine.java:

import com.github.coderodde.game.connect4.ConnectFourBoard;
import static com.github.coderodde.game.connect4.ConnectFourBoard.COLUMNS;
import com.github.coderodde.game.connect4.ConnectFourHeuristicFunction;
import com.github.coderodde.game.zerosum.HeuristicFunction;
import com.github.coderodde.game.zerosum.PlayerType;
import com.github.coderodde.game.zerosum.SearchEngine;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * This class implements the parallel Alpha-beta pruning for playing Connect 
 * Four.
 * 
 * @version 1.0.0 (Jun 7, 2024) 
 * @since 1.0.0 (Jun 7, 2024)
 */
public final class ParallelConnectFourAlphaBetaPruningSearchEngine 
implements SearchEngine<ConnectFourBoard> {

    private static final int MINIMUM_SEED_DEPTH = 2;
    private static final int DEFAULT_SEED_DEPTH = 2;
    private static final int MINIMUM_DEPTH = 5;
    
    private final HeuristicFunction<ConnectFourBoard> heuristicFunction;
    private int requestedDepth;
    private int seedDepth;
    
    /**
     * Constructs this search engine.
     * 
     * @param heuristicFunction the heuristic function used to score the states.
     * @param seedDepth         the depth of the seed states.
     */
    public ParallelConnectFourAlphaBetaPruningSearchEngine(
            final HeuristicFunction<ConnectFourBoard> heuristicFunction,
            final int seedDepth) {
        
        this.heuristicFunction = heuristicFunction;
        this.seedDepth = seedDepth;
    }
    
    /**
     * Constructs this search engine.
     * 
     * @param heuristicFunction the heuristic function used to score the states.
     */
    public ParallelConnectFourAlphaBetaPruningSearchEngine(
            final ConnectFourHeuristicFunction heuristicFunction) {
        
        this(heuristicFunction, DEFAULT_SEED_DEPTH);
    }
    
    /**
     * Performs the actual search for the next move state.
     * 
     * @param root  the root state of the search.
     * @param depth the depth of the search.
     * 
     * @return next move state.
     */
    @Override
    public ConnectFourBoard 
        search(final ConnectFourBoard root, 
               final int depth,
               final PlayerType playerType) {
    
        this.requestedDepth = depth;
        
        if (depth < Math.max(MINIMUM_SEED_DEPTH, MINIMUM_DEPTH)) {
            // If too shallow, delegate to single-threaded AI:
            return new ConnectFourAlphaBetaPruningSearchEngine(
                    heuristicFunction).search(root,
                                              depth);
        }
        
        // Obtains the list of seed states. May lower the 'seedDepth':
        final List<ConnectFourBoard> seedStates = getSeedStates(root,
                                                                playerType);
        
        // Randomly shuffle the seed states. This is a trivial load balancing:
        Collections.shuffle(seedStates);
        
        // Get the list of thread workloads:
        final List<List<ConnectFourBoard>> threadLoads = 
                bucketizeSeedStates(seedStates, 
                                    Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        
        // Create the list of search threads:
        final List<SearchThread> searchThreadList = 
                new ArrayList<>(threadLoads.size());
        
        // Populate the search threads:
        for (final List<ConnectFourBoard> threadLoad : threadLoads) {
            final SearchThread searchThread =
                    new SearchThread(
                            threadLoad,
                            heuristicFunction,
                            seedDepth % 2 == 0 ? PlayerType.MAXIMIZING_PLAYER :
                                                 PlayerType.MINIMIZING_PLAYER,
                            depth - seedDepth);
            
            searchThread.start();
            
            searchThreadList.add(searchThread);
        }
        
        // Wait for all the threads to complete:
        for (final SearchThread searchThread : searchThreadList) {
            try {
                searchThread.join();
            } catch (final InterruptedException ex) {
                
            }
        }
        
        // Compute the global seed state score map:
        final Map<ConnectFourBoard, Double> globalScoreMap = 
                getGlobalScoreMap(searchThreadList);
        
        // Construct the seed state heuristic function:
        final SeedStateHeuristicFunction seedHeuristicFunction = 
                new SeedStateHeuristicFunction(globalScoreMap);
        
        // Just compute above the seed states:
        return alphaBetaImplRoot(root, 
                                 seedHeuristicFunction,
                                 requestedDepth,
                                 playerType);
    }
    
    /**
     * The topmost call to the search routine.
     * 
     * @param root              the root state.
     * @param heuristicFunction the heuristic function.
     * @param seedDepth         the seed state depth.
     * 
     * @return the next move state.
     */
    private ConnectFourBoard 
        alphaBetaImplRoot(
                final ConnectFourBoard root,
                final SeedStateHeuristicFunction seedHeuristicFunction,
                final int depth,
                final PlayerType playerType) {
            
        ConnectFourBoard bestMoveState = null;
        
        if (playerType == PlayerType.MAXIMIZING_PLAYER) {
            
            double alpha = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
            double value = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
            double tentativeValue = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

            for (int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++) {
                // Try to make a ply at column 'x':
                if (!root.makePly(x, PlayerType.MAXIMIZING_PLAYER)) {
                    // The entire column at X=x is full. Omit.
                    continue;
                }

                value = Math.max(value,
                                 alphaBetaImplAboveSeedLayer(
                                         root,
                                         depth - 1,
                                         alpha,
                                         Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
                                         PlayerType.MINIMIZING_PLAYER,
                                         seedHeuristicFunction));
                
                if (tentativeValue < value) {
                    tentativeValue = value;
                    bestMoveState = new ConnectFourBoard(root);
                }
                
                // Undo the previously made ply:
                root.unmakePly(x);
                
                // Possibly raise alpha:
                alpha = Math.max(alpha, value);
            }
        
            return bestMoveState;
        } else {
            
            double beta  = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
            double value = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
            double tentativeValue = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
            
            for (int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++) {
                // Try to make a ply at column 'x':
                if (!root.makePly(x, PlayerType.MINIMIZING_PLAYER)) {
                    // The entire column at X=x is full. Omit.
                    continue;
                }
                
                value = Math.min(value,
                                 alphaBetaImplAboveSeedLayer(
                                        root,
                                        depth - 1,
                                        Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
                                        beta,
                                        PlayerType.MAXIMIZING_PLAYER,
                                        seedHeuristicFunction));
                
                if (tentativeValue > value) {
                    tentativeValue = value;
                    bestMoveState = new ConnectFourBoard(root);
                }
                
                // Undo the previously made ply:
                root.unmakePly(x);
                
                // Possibly lower beta:
                beta = Math.min(beta, value);
            }
        }
            
        // The best known value
        return bestMoveState;
    }
        
    private double alphaBetaImplAboveSeedLayer(
            final ConnectFourBoard root,
            final int depth,
            double alpha,
            double beta,
            final PlayerType rootPlayerType,
            final SeedStateHeuristicFunction seedStateHeuristicFunction) {
        
        if (depth == 0 || root.isTerminal()) {
            // Once here, we have a loss, victory or tie:
            return heuristicFunction.evaluate(root, depth);
        }
        
        if (requestedDepth - depth == seedDepth) {
            // Once here, we have reached the seed level.
            // 0 as the second argument is ignored. Just return the
            // score for 'root' as we have computed its score in a 
            // thread:
            return seedStateHeuristicFunction.evaluate(root, 0);
        }
        
        if (rootPlayerType == PlayerType.MAXIMIZING_PLAYER) {
            double value = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

            for (int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++) {
                if (!root.makePly(x, PlayerType.MAXIMIZING_PLAYER)) {
                    continue;
                }

                value = Math.max(value, 
                                 alphaBetaImplAboveSeedLayer(
                                         root,
                                         depth - 1,
                                         alpha,
                                         beta,
                                         PlayerType.MINIMIZING_PLAYER,
                                         seedStateHeuristicFunction));
                root.unmakePly(x);

                if (value > beta) {
                    break;
                }

                alpha = Math.max(alpha, value);
            }   

            return value;
        } else {
            double value = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

            for (int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++) {
                if (!root.makePly(x, PlayerType.MINIMIZING_PLAYER)) {
                    continue;
                }

                value = Math.min(value,
                                 alphaBetaImplAboveSeedLayer(
                                         root,
                                         depth - 1,
                                         alpha,
                                         beta,
                                         PlayerType.MAXIMIZING_PLAYER,
                                         seedStateHeuristicFunction));
                root.unmakePly(x);

                if (value < alpha) {
                    break;
                }

                beta = Math.min(beta, value);
            }

            return value;
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Combines all the score maps into one global map for searching above the
     * seed states.
     * 
     * @param searchThreadList the list of search threads.
     * 
     * @return the combined global score map.
     */
    private static Map<ConnectFourBoard, Double>
         getGlobalScoreMap(final List<SearchThread> searchThreadList) {
        
        // Construct the global score map:
        final Map<ConnectFourBoard, Double> globalScoreMap = new HashMap<>();
        
        // Load the global score map from each search thread score map:
        for (final SearchThread searchThread : searchThreadList) {
            globalScoreMap.putAll(searchThread.getScoreMap());
        }
        
        return globalScoreMap;
    }
    
    /**
     * Splits the list of seed states into list of lists of seed states.
     * 
     * @param seedStates  the list of all the seed states.
     * @param threadCount the number of threads to assume.
     * 
     * @return list of seed state buckets. One for each thread.
     */
    private static List<List<ConnectFourBoard>> 
        bucketizeSeedStates(final List<ConnectFourBoard> seedStates,
                            final int threadCount) {
            
        // Construct a list with capacity sufficient to accommodate all the
        // buckets:
        final List<List<ConnectFourBoard>> threadBuckets = 
                new ArrayList<>(threadCount);
        
        // The basic number of seed states per thread bucket:
        final int basicNumberOfSeedsPerBucket = seedStates.size() / threadCount;
        
        // The seed state index:
        int index = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
            // Construct the new bucket. +1 in order to add additional possible
            // seed state in case 'threadCount' does not divide
            // 'seedStates.size()':
            final List<ConnectFourBoard> bucket = 
                    new ArrayList<>(basicNumberOfSeedsPerBucket + 1);
            
            // Load the current bucket:
            for (int j = 0; j < basicNumberOfSeedsPerBucket; j++, index++) {
                bucket.add(seedStates.get(index));
            }
            
            // Add the bucket to the bucket list:
            threadBuckets.add(bucket);
        }
        
        // How many threads should receive one more additional seed state?
        final int remainingStates = seedStates.size() % threadCount;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < remainingStates; i++, index++) {
            threadBuckets.get(i).add(seedStates.get(index));
        }
        
        return threadBuckets;
    }
    
    /**
     * Computes the list of seed states. The idea is that each search thread 
     * starts its search from a seed state. This method resembles breadth-
     * first search in a tree. This method may update {@link #seedDepth}.
     * 
     * @param root the actual root state of the search.
     * 
     * @return the list of seed states.
     */
    private List<ConnectFourBoard> getSeedStates(final ConnectFourBoard root,
                                                 PlayerType playerType) {
        
        List<ConnectFourBoard> levelA = new ArrayList<>();
        List<ConnectFourBoard> levelB = new ArrayList<>();
        
        // Initialize the expansion:
        levelA.add(root);
        
        int effectiveSeedDepth = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < seedDepth; i++) {
            // Load next state layer:
            for (final ConnectFourBoard cfb : levelA) {
                levelB.addAll(cfb.expand(playerType));
            }
            
            if (levelB.isEmpty() == false) {
                effectiveSeedDepth++;
            } else {
                // Once here, the root state is missing very few plies:
                seedDepth = effectiveSeedDepth;
                return levelA;
            }
            
            levelA.clear();
            levelA.addAll(levelB);
            levelB.clear();
            
            // Assume the opposite player:
            playerType = playerType.flip();
        }
        
        return levelA;
    }

    @Override
    public ConnectFourBoard search(final ConnectFourBoard root,
                                   final int depth) {
        
        return search(root, depth, PlayerType.MAXIMIZING_PLAYER);
    }
}


/**
 * This class implements the actual search routine starting from seed states.
 */
final class SearchThread extends Thread {

    /**
     * The list of seed states to process.
     */
    private final List<ConnectFourBoard> workload;

    /**
     * This map maps each seed states to its score after computation.
     */
    private final Map<ConnectFourBoard, Double> scoreMap;

    /**
     * The heuristic function for evaluating intermediate states.
     */
    private final HeuristicFunction<ConnectFourBoard> heuristicFunction;

    /**
     * The beginning player type.
     */
    private final PlayerType rootPlayerType;

    /**
     * The (maximal) search depth.
     */
    private final int depth;

    /**
     * Constructs this search thread.
     * 
     * @param workload          the workload list of seed states.
     * @param heuristicFunction the heuristic function.
     * @param rootPlayerType    the beginning player type.
     * @param depth             the maximal search depth.
     */
    SearchThread(final List<ConnectFourBoard> workload,
                 final HeuristicFunction<ConnectFourBoard> 
                       heuristicFunction,
                 final PlayerType rootPlayerType,
                 final int depth) {

        this.workload = workload;
        this.scoreMap = new HashMap<>(workload.size());
        this.heuristicFunction = heuristicFunction;
        this.rootPlayerType = rootPlayerType;
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    /**
     * Returns computed score map mapping each seed state to its score.
     * 
     * @return the score map.
     */
    Map<ConnectFourBoard, Double> getScoreMap() {
        return scoreMap;
    }

    /**
     * Runs the search in this thread.
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (final ConnectFourBoard root : workload) {
            final double score = 
                    alphaBetaImpl(
                            root,
                            depth, 
                            Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
                            Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
                            rootPlayerType);

            scoreMap.put(root, score);
        }
    }

    private double alphaBetaImpl(final ConnectFourBoard root,
                                 final int depth,
                                 double alpha,
                                 double beta,
                                 final PlayerType rootPlayerType) {
        
        if (depth == 0 || root.isTerminal()) {
            return heuristicFunction.evaluate(root, depth);
        }

        if (rootPlayerType == PlayerType.MAXIMIZING_PLAYER) {
            double value = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

            for (int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++) {
                if (!root.makePly(x, PlayerType.MAXIMIZING_PLAYER)) {
                    continue;
                }

                value = Math.max(value, 
                                 alphaBetaImpl(root,
                                               depth - 1,
                                               alpha,
                                               beta,
                                               PlayerType.MINIMIZING_PLAYER));

                root.unmakePly(x);

                if (value > beta) {
                    break;
                }

                alpha = Math.max(alpha, value);
            }   

            return value;
        } else {
            double value = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

            for (int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++) {
                if (!root.makePly(x, PlayerType.MINIMIZING_PLAYER)) {
                    continue;
                }

                value = Math.min(value,
                                 alphaBetaImpl(root,
                                               depth - 1,
                                               alpha,
                                               beta,
                                               PlayerType.MAXIMIZING_PLAYER));

                root.unmakePly(x);

                if (value < alpha) {
                    break;
                }

                beta = Math.min(beta, value);
            }

            return value;
        }
    }
}
    
/**
 * This class implements the heuristic function for the seed states.
 */
final class SeedStateHeuristicFunction
        implements HeuristicFunction<ConnectFourBoard> {

    private final Map<ConnectFourBoard, Double> scoreMap;

    SeedStateHeuristicFunction(
            final Map<ConnectFourBoard, Double> scoreMap) {

        this.scoreMap = scoreMap;
    }

    @Override
    public double evaluate(ConnectFourBoard state, int depth) {
        return scoreMap.get(state);
    }
}

Comparison output
The comparison program shows the following results on a octocore CPU (8 physical cores):
AlphaBetaPruningSearchEngine in 4640 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
ConnectFourAlphaBetaPruningSearchEngine in 2764 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
ParallelConnectFourAlphaBetaPruningSearchEngine in 1818 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
<<< AI vs. AI >>>
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial AI depth:   9
Parallel AI depth: 8
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial engine in 1027 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|X|O|.|.|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Parallel engine in 122 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|X|O|.|.|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial engine in 1589 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|X|O|.|.|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Parallel engine in 164 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|X|O|.|O|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial engine in 2016 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|.|.|
|.|.|X|O|X|O|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Parallel engine in 225 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|O|.|
|.|.|X|O|X|O|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial engine in 1787 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|.|O|.|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Parallel engine in 209 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|O|O|.|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial engine in 2535 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|.|.|.|
|.|.|X|O|O|O|.|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Parallel engine in 63 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|.|O|.|
|.|.|X|O|O|O|.|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial engine in 3651 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|X|.|
|.|.|.|X|.|O|.|
|.|.|X|O|O|O|.|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|.|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Parallel engine in 105 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|X|.|
|.|.|.|X|.|O|.|
|.|.|X|O|O|O|.|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial engine in 2437 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|X|.|
|.|.|.|X|.|O|.|
|.|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Parallel engine in 164 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|X|.|
|.|.|.|X|O|O|.|
|.|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial engine in 2468 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|.|X|.|
|.|.|.|X|O|O|.|
|.|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Parallel engine in 102 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|O|X|.|
|.|.|.|X|O|O|.|
|.|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial engine in 1248 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|X|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|O|X|.|
|.|.|.|X|O|O|.|
|.|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Parallel engine in 92 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|X|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|O|X|.|
|.|.|.|X|O|O|O|
|.|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial engine in 1271 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|.|X|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|O|X|X|
|.|.|.|X|O|O|O|
|.|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Parallel engine in 126 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|X|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|O|X|X|
|.|.|.|X|O|O|O|
|.|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial engine in 257 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|X|.|.|
|.|.|.|X|O|X|X|
|.|.|X|X|O|O|O|
|.|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Parallel engine in 52 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|X|.|.|
|.|.|O|X|O|X|X|
|.|.|X|X|O|O|O|
|.|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial engine in 47 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|X|.|.|
|.|.|O|X|O|X|X|
|.|.|X|X|O|O|O|
|X|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Parallel engine in 19 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|X|.|.|
|.|.|O|X|O|X|X|
|O|.|X|X|O|O|O|
|X|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial engine in 39 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|.|O|X|.|.|
|X|.|O|X|O|X|X|
|O|.|X|X|O|O|O|
|X|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Parallel engine in 17 milliseconds.
|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|O|O|X|.|.|
|X|.|O|X|O|X|X|
|O|.|X|X|O|O|O|
|X|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial engine in 48 milliseconds.
|.|.|X|.|.|.|.|
|.|.|O|O|X|.|.|
|X|.|O|X|O|X|X|
|O|.|X|X|O|O|O|
|X|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Parallel engine in 8 milliseconds.
|.|.|X|.|.|.|.|
|O|.|O|O|X|.|.|
|X|.|O|X|O|X|X|
|O|.|X|X|O|O|O|
|X|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial engine in 22 milliseconds.
|.|.|X|.|.|.|.|
|O|.|O|O|X|X|.|
|X|.|O|X|O|X|X|
|O|.|X|X|O|O|O|
|X|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Parallel engine in 6 milliseconds.
|.|.|X|.|.|O|.|
|O|.|O|O|X|X|.|
|X|.|O|X|O|X|X|
|O|.|X|X|O|O|O|
|X|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial engine in 3 milliseconds.
|.|.|X|X|.|O|.|
|O|.|O|O|X|X|.|
|X|.|O|X|O|X|X|
|O|.|X|X|O|O|O|
|X|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Parallel engine in 3 milliseconds.
|O|.|X|X|.|O|.|
|O|.|O|O|X|X|.|
|X|.|O|X|O|X|X|
|O|.|X|X|O|O|O|
|X|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial engine in 0 milliseconds.
|O|.|X|X|X|O|.|
|O|.|O|O|X|X|.|
|X|.|O|X|O|X|X|
|O|.|X|X|O|O|O|
|X|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Parallel engine in 2 milliseconds.
|O|.|X|X|X|O|.|
|O|.|O|O|X|X|O|
|X|.|O|X|O|X|X|
|O|.|X|X|O|O|O|
|X|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial engine in 0 milliseconds.
|O|.|X|X|X|O|X|
|O|.|O|O|X|X|O|
|X|.|O|X|O|X|X|
|O|.|X|X|O|O|O|
|X|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|.|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Parallel engine in 2 milliseconds.
|O|.|X|X|X|O|X|
|O|.|O|O|X|X|O|
|X|.|O|X|O|X|X|
|O|.|X|X|O|O|O|
|X|.|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|O|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Serial engine in 0 milliseconds.
|O|.|X|X|X|O|X|
|O|.|O|O|X|X|O|
|X|.|O|X|O|X|X|
|O|.|X|X|O|O|O|
|X|X|X|O|O|O|X|
|X|O|X|O|X|O|O|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Parallel engine in 3 milliseconds.
RESULT: Parallel engine wins.
Serial engine in total 20445 milliseconds.
Parallel engine in total 1484 milliseconds.

Critique request
Please, tell me whatever comes to mind.

A 3x speedup sounds like a reasonable start for 8 cores.  Read up on Amdahl's law and consider where your code has serial processing and thread creation/destruction/communication overheads.

@TobySpeight I am well aware about Amdahl's law and its implications. However, I was expecting to see speed up of 6.

You're probably not getting any replies because the subject is not very trivial and there isn't much to complain about your code. I would have written this as a comment as I don't think it really qualifies as a proper review, but I ran out of characters.
Have you evaluated how a ThreadPoolExecutor affects the performance? It would seem like a tool designed for this job, since you're always creating the same number of threads to handle a large amount of workload items.
You probably want to use HashMap.newHashMap(workload.size()) instead of the constructor, as it guarantees that a rehashing won't happen.
Consider splitting alphaBetaImpl into two methods, one for minimizing and one or maximizing, so you don't need a long if-else block.

Fair enough. Your text well qualifies as an answer. I will try your threading advice later.

Took a look at https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html I don't quite get how it is any better than creating two threads for each physical core and run almost equal number of subtasks on each thread.
